# GASで実行者のユーザー名を自動代入したい

Tags: google-apps-script

`var txt = '';` の部分に、このscriptを実行した人を自動的に入力してほしいのですが、ここからどのようにすればいいでしょうか。

`var url` の部分は秘密保護ため一部削除しています。

```
function onOpen2() {
  var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com';
  var text = '見た人の名前を自動挿入する';
  var payload = {
    "text" : text
    }
  var json = JSON.stringify(payload); 
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    "payload" : json
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

現在のセッションのユーザー(そのGASを開いていたユーザー)のメールアドレス(ログインID)は`Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`で取得できます。

ドキュメント: [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)

ただ、これで得られるUserには`getEmail()`しかメソッドが無く、得られるのはメールアドレス(ログインID)のみです。ユーザーの氏名等も取得したいとなるとそのメールアドレスから[Directory API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)を使ってユーザー情報を取得する必要があります。